# Update all posts in a loop everyday

Tags: posts

Im new to wordpress and I want to try out how to make all the posts therein a wordpress site update everyday with a loop every minute or so.

I haven't done anything yet. I just want to know if its possible or is there any other approach I could start on.

Many thanks!

Comment: which kind of update do you want to make ? show us an example

Comment: Just update all the posts. Like a post or a page and other custom post types. Is it possible? Like im talking about the whole posts and pages of the overall site.

Comment: Please define “update”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WordPress has a cron system called [WP Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) (which is not the same as a *nix cron). The idea is that your plugin would register a task (a WordPress action callback) that performs the desired logic (in your case, running the code that updates all the posts).

Comment: One word of caution - WP Cron only fires when someone visits the site, so if you're working on a low-traffic site, the updates won't be made until someone actually visits. It might be safer to hit your file with an actual cron job if you want to make sure the content updates regardless of visitors.